# Tooltip with content in Material-UI

Tags: material-ui

I have following tooltip:

```
export const EstimateTableActions = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Tooltip title="Actions" aria-label="add">
        <Fab color="primary">
          <MoreVertIcon />
        </Fab>
      </Tooltip>
    </>
  );
};
```

which looks like:

[image]

And I want to add content to the tooltip, I want to have some div with my actions after click, in the documentation there is no any example on that, any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use speed dial component to add actions of your choice --

[image]

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Backdrop from '@material-ui/core/Backdrop';
import SpeedDial from '@material-ui/lab/SpeedDial';
import SpeedDialIcon from '@material-ui/lab/SpeedDialIcon';
import SpeedDialAction from '@material-ui/lab/SpeedDialAction';
import FileCopyIcon from '@material-ui/icons/FileCopyOutlined';
import SaveIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Save';
import PrintIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Print';
import ShareIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Share';
import FavoriteIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Favorite';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    height: 380,
    transform: 'translateZ(0px)',
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  speedDial: {
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: theme.spacing(2),
    right: theme.spacing(2),
  },
}));

const actions = [
  { icon: <FileCopyIcon />, name: 'Copy' },
  { icon: <SaveIcon />, name: 'Save' },
  { icon: <PrintIcon />, name: 'Print' },
  { icon: <ShareIcon />, name: 'Share' },
  { icon: <FavoriteIcon />, name: 'Like' },
];

export default function SpeedDialTooltipOpen() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const [hidden, setHidden] = React.useState(false);

  const handleVisibility = () => {
    setHidden((prevHidden) => !prevHidden);
  };

  const handleOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Button onClick={handleVisibility}>Toggle Speed Dial</Button>
      <Backdrop open={open} />
      <SpeedDial
        ariaLabel="SpeedDial tooltip example"
        className={classes.speedDial}
        hidden={hidden}
        icon={<SpeedDialIcon />}
        onClose={handleClose}
        onOpen={handleOpen}
        open={true}
      >
        {actions.map((action) => (
          <SpeedDialAction
            key={action.name}
            icon={action.icon}
            tooltipTitle={action.name}
            tooltipOpen
            onClick={handleClose}
          />
        ))}
      </SpeedDial>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Working sandbox here - https://codesandbox.io/s/qogpp